# Deserialize array of json objects with json object inside

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

How can I deserialize array of json objects in c#? Here's my json:

```
[{"id":"255521115", "user":"username","userinfo":{"id":"158","online":"false"}}]
```

I have this code to get username:

```
 [JsonProperty("user")]
 public string Username { get; set; }
```

How can I get values of the userinfo? I want online value that is inside userinfo object.

Comment: you either clipped some closing brackets to post or your JSON is not valid

Comment: I clipped closing bracket, thanks for notice :)

Comment: Still not valid; likely should be `[{"id": "255521115","user": "username","userinfo": {"id": "158", "online": "false"}}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is one cool feature in VS2013. If you copy your JSON to clipboard and in Visual Studio click `EDIT -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes` it will generate class structure for you. All you need is to rename some properties if you want to. In your case modified version of classes will be:

```
public class Obj
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("User")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public Userinfo Userinfo { get; set; }
}

public class Userinfo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Online { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can easily deserialize your JSON string:

```
var json = @"[{""id"":""255521115"", ""user"":""username"",""userinfo"":{""id"":""158"",""online"":""false""}}]";
var objs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Obj>>(json);
```

Comment: I had no idea about that Visual Studio trick.  Great time saver.  Thanks so much!

Comment: That trick is also available on VS 2022. Time saver.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class classname
{
   //Create property to hold value
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

now deserialization will work:

```
using (var sr = new StringReader(json))
using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    var js = new JsonSerializer();
    var u = js.Deserialize<classname>(jr);
    Console.WriteLine(u.Username );
}
```

i think this will help you to deserialize