# Deserialize array of objects using Newtonsoft's deserializer

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2015, json.net, deserialization

I am struggling to deserialize JSON data that consists of an array of similar objects that have identical structure inside, but each object having a different name that I cannot predict.

The overall structure of JSON is like this ([source here](http://90d5dd.ethosdistro.com/?json=yes)):

[image]

The objects named 1be2f7 and 193ff5 have an identical structure.

I have no problem deserializing if I hardcode the names of these two objects, but how do I do that without hardcoding?

Here is what I've tried:

```
    public List<Rig> rigs { get; set; }
```

But that gives this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Eth.Rig]' because the
>   type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To
>   fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])
>   or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g.
>   not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array
>   or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'rigs.1be2f7', line 1, position
>   18.

There is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473886/deserialize-array-of-json-objects-with-json-object-inside) but its accepted answer doesn't work for me because Visual Studio also just hardcodes the names of the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - turns out to be really simple.

Change this:

```
public List<Rig> rigs { get; set; }
```

To this:

```
public Dictionary<Rig> rigs { get; set; }
```

Then use this to loop through:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Rig> entry in rigs)
{
    // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
}
```

Comment: don't you want to mark it as a result? :) your question is still open

Comment: @AshkanSirous please look at the date of the post before commenting. Self-answers can be accepted after two days only.